# Сортировка двумерного массива в грид

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты!

У меня вот такая проблема... мне нужно отсортировать записи по возрастанию в стринг гриде. У меня получилось так. Код Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button19Click (Sender:TObject);
const
    SIZE = 6;
var
    a: array[0..SIZE, 1..SIZE] of char;
    i, j: integer;
    temp: char;
begin
    for j := 1 to 15 do
        a[0, j] := StrToChar (StringGrid1.Cells[0, j]);
    a[0, j + 1] := StrToChar (StringGrid1.Cells[0, j + 1]);
    if a[0, j] > a[0, j + 1] then
        temp := a[0, j];
        a[0, j] := a[0, j + 1];
        a[0, j + 1]:= temp
    else
        j := j + 1;
end;
```

Но ошибку выдает в 10 и 11 строчках. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перевести записи из грида в тип char. )

Answer (score 2):

А еще Begin и End попропускал как в цыкле, так и в if-е:

```
begin 
  for j := 1 to SIZE do 
    begin 
      a[0, j] := StrToChar (StringGrid1.Cells[0, j]);
      a[0, j + 1] := StrToChar (StringGrid1.Cells[0, j + 1]); 
      if a[0, j] > a[0, j + 1] then
        begin 
          temp := a[0, j]; 
          a[0, j] := a[0, j + 1]; 
          a[0, j + 1]:= temp;
        end 
     else j := j + 1;
   end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for j := 1 to 15 do
    a[0, j] := StringGrid1.Cells[0, j][1];
a[0, j + 1] := StringGrid1.Cells[0, j + 1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас индекс меняется от 1 до 15, а константа `SIZE = 6`

Тогда уж если на то пошло:

```
for j := 1 to SIZE do
    a[0, j] := StrToChar (StringGrid1.Cells[0, j]);
```

Плюс предыдущий оратор.